# How to display raw xml file in php to web browser

Tags: php, xml, file, browser, new-operator

Hi i got an xml file and i want to display it on a website.
I tried everything what i found and tried to do it my self but im a newbie to any code language. 
My code is this right now:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

    $xml = simplexml_load_file(xmlfile.xml) ;

echo $xml ;



?>
```

And the output what i see when i go to my website is nothing just a warning about: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

But i cant see anything. So please can someone help me write a code that outputs the whole xml file including xml declaration , tags and node values?

Comment: Rather than convert it using `$xml = simplexml_load_file(xmlfile.xml) ;` you can just display the file using `readfile("xmlfile.xml");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use the [`simplexml_load_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php): there is another function to read a file, this function is [`file_get_contents($filename)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).
Here is a simple code to use:

```php
<?php
// Set the encoding to XML
header('Content-type: text/xml');

// Get contents of the file
$xml = file_get_contents("xmlfile.xml") ;

// Print contents
echo $xml;

?>
```

I hope it helped you! *And sorry for the language mistakes ;)*

Comment: This answer is identical to the previous one. It doesn't add anything new.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It works for me.

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: text/xml");
  $yourFile = "xmlfile.xml";
  $file = file_get_contents($yourFile);

  echo $file;
```

If you insist on simple xml you can write like this.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("xmlfile.xml");

echo $xml->asXML();
```